# Regular Expression on Google Analytics: Including and Excluding

Tags: python, regex

Using Regular Expression, I am trying to **match** these URLs on my Google Analytics:

- /leeds-parking-spaces-and-garages-to-rent
- /norwich-parking

but **exclude** those ones:

- /Leeds-parking-spaces-and-garages-to-rent
- /Norwich-parking

As you can see, the only difference between them being the capital 'L' and 'N' in the URLs to exclude.

I have tried using this code in an **exclude** filter in Google Analytics, and other variations of the code, but have had no success:

```
^/(\W)orwich-parking$|^/(\W)eeds-parking-spaces-and-garages-to-rent$
```

Comment: Do you really need something as powerful as regexp to match two URLs ? I feel like a plain old `txt == value1 or txt == value2` will do the tricks and be way more readable.

Comment: I will bear this in mind for next time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`\W` means not a word, not lowercase only, you can use `[a-z]` instead, assuming that you're after a letter of the alphabet